# How to do pagination with newer versions of angular and bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have found some links that show how to do it, but i am using angular 1.3.13, and angular-ui-bootstrap 0.13.0, and i can not display template for pagination...

here is the html:

```
  <ul class="white">
     <li ng-repeat="p in placed1">{{p}}</li>
  </ul>
  <pagination boundary-links="true"
              max-size="3"
              items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
              total-items="placed.length"
              ng-model="currentPage"
              ng-change="pageChanged()">
</pagination>
```

and here is the script

```
$scope.placed1 = [];
$scope.placed2 = [];

$scope.itemsPerPage = 10;
$scope.currentPage = 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        $scope.placed2.push("test " + i);
    }

    $scope.figureOutTodosToDisplay = function () {
        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage);
        var end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;
        $scope.placed1 = $scope.placed2.slice(begin, end);
    };

    $scope.figureOutTodosToDisplay();

    $scope.pageChanged = function () {
        $scope.figureOutTodosToDisplay();
    };
```

Comment: are you found any solution??